# Visual Studio 2022 for Mac, ‘Could not connect to debugger’ error popup and ‘Device is invalid’ error in Deploying to Device window

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am developing app in Xamarin Forms using Visual Studio for Mac.

I have updated macOS, Visual Studio and Xcode. Now I am running macOS Monterey version 12.5.1 and have Visual Studio 2022 for Mac version 17.4.1 and Xcode 14 installed.

I am trying to build iOS app on iPhone 5s having iOS 12.4.

Now I am getting dialog popup ‘Could not connect to debugger’ and below error:

error MT1006: Could not install the application ‘MyProject.App.iOS/bin/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone6.2-12.5.6/MyProject.App.iOS.app’ on the device ‘My Iphone': Device is invalid (0xe8000084)

In last month it was working  but at that time I have app which is already installed through Visual Studio 2019, Xcode 11 and on that installed app, I am building app through updated versions Visual Studio 2022 for Mac and Xcode 14.

Now I have uninstalled that app and trying to build through Visual Studio 2022 then getting popup ‘Could not connect to debugger’.

I have gone through some articles, it is mentioned that Xcode 14 supports on-device debugging for iOS 11 and later. Also Xcode 14 will build 64-bit apps. So iPhone 5s will support.

First thing I would like to know iPhone 5s is supported or not with these updated versions?

Is there any other limitations or restriction for iPhone 5s to do not support as it is giving an error 'Device is invalid'? Or is there anything I need to update?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are some restrictions for the device. Only `64-bit` iOS devices are supported. As of `iOS 11`, Apple no longer allows running iOS apps on the 32-bit architecture (devices earlier than iPhone 5s).

**Update:**

To test on a physical device, the device must be `provisioned`.

- To begin with, you need to have an active subscription to Apple's
  Developer Program , or use [Free
  Provisioning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos).
  There are a number of limitations when provisioning in this way, as
  [detailed
  here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/free-provisioning?tabs=macos).
- And then, visit the Apple Developer Portal and register as an Apple
  developer, it is necessary to have an Apple ID .
  Then request a Certificate, and register the device on which the application will be deployed.
  Then provision your iOS device (Automatically / Manually ) .

For more details, you can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/#provisioning-for-application-services.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I have searched for iPhone 5s is 32 bit or 64 bit then I found that it is 64 bit.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It may be related to the `provisioning profile`. You can check my update.

Comment: Device is provisioned. Provisioning profile and certificate is correct. I have tried to run on iPhone 7 then it is working on it but not on iPhone 5s.

Comment: If you can run on iPhone7 successfully, then the issue could be related with the iPhone 5s, not provisioning profile.

Comment: Yes. But yet I have not get any conclusive evidence that iPhone 5s supports or not.

Comment: May I know the iOS version of the iPhone 7 and iPhone 5s?

Comment: For iPhone 7, iOS 15.5 and for iPhone 5s, iOS 12.4

Comment: You can try to upgrade iPhone 5s to iOS 15.5 to see if the issue still exists..

Comment: Actually iPhone 5s does not support iOS 13 and later.